# Which Azure AD app registration auth flow should I be using?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application, azure-authentication

I currently have an Azure AD app registration setup for my ASP.NET CORE MVC (view includes a VueJS SPA) and all works well. We use access tokens with delegated permissions so the backend controllers can call MS Graph API requests. However, I am now trying to clean up my framework and make my VueJS SPA completely separate from my controllers and convert my backend to a ASP.NET CORE web api to get rid of the view dependent. So this is what I am trying to accomplish but I am not sure what settings I need for my new Azure AD App Registration:

1. User goes to site's login page
2. User clicks sign in and is redirected to Azure AD Login Screen
3. User logs in and is redirected back to front end of application authenticated
4. User now has access to make access the web API
5. THe web API should now have application permissions and not being doing stuff on behalf of user. So basically all communication done with MS Graph is based on the application's authentication and permissions and not the users.

I was researching and this almost seems like the method I want:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app

This seems like what I want however I was worried this is only providing the authentication for the user to access my ASP.NET Core Web API but does it also handle the Web API being able to access MS Graph API? Or is this completely wrong and there is a better approach I am missing here as MS Docs have so many new and old approaches its confusing to know what to go with. I also do not own the Azure AD subscription or setup the registration so I have to lay it out clearly for the person who does so I want to get this right the first go around.

Comment: In your case you have to use Application Permission (not delegate permission) for what you wish to do. However consider if you want to use it, Application Permissions are for automation processes and daemons. You have a user logged in.

Comment: There is the possibility we may switch to Okta for logging in as there are other services that our company communicates with via Okta. In this case would you switch to application permission? That was my main reason is because I figured it gave us options to use other IDP but still let us know MS Graph API.

Comment: If you access model is user --> your WS --> MS Graph, then I suppose it should be fine to use application permission as your WS logs the access (and provides for any security considerations). Since at Azure level it is only the application access that is seen. By the way, this is my opinion only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you shared in the question used Azure AD B2C, not very sure if you are using B2C, but it's a little different with B2B. My post below is based on B2B.

First, if you want your API to call MS Graph API on behalf of the user or on behalf of the application? Because in your old structure, you used delegated permission.

If you still want to use delegated permission, then you should [on behalf of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). If you want to use application permission, you should use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

It would be easy to use client credential flow if you don't take the API authorization into consideration, I mean you can call your backend API anonymously. Then you only need to ask the one managing Azure AD to consent the requirement Grapu API Application permissions. Then in your web API code, using code below to call graph API. My code is based on Microsoft.Graph V4.x version, not V5.x

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

If you don't want your backend API without Authorization, then you can feel free to use some authorization scheme. But since you already used AAD, you might also want to [use AAD to protect your web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview).

And since you already used AAD to protect your API, then you are certainly able to use on behalf of flow to call Graph API with delegated permission. Firstly, if you used AAD to protect your WEB API, in your Program.cs, you should have code like below. This means you should use a correct access token in the request header to visit the controller having `[Authorize]` attribute.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

or

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
```

In this scenario, we can also add Graph SDK like code below.

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Then in the protected Controller, just inject graph client and use it to call Graph API directly. It already authorized by on behalf of flow. If you don't want to use Graph SDK, you can also inject `ITokenAcquisition` to generate new access token.

```
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync() {
    var b = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
    
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.Read" });

    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:7212/WeatherForecast")
    {
        Headers =
        {
            { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ accessToken}
        }
    };

    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

    var res = "";
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: let me first say thank you for taking the time to write this up. It is more helpful than you can believe. Since we may shift to Okta and away from AAD for authenticating users I think we want to stay away from delegated permissions correct? I do not really need to to do things on behalf of users but instead look as though the app is doing this via a service account. So I guess client credential flow is what I need then. So for client credential flow do I need to add anything to my program.cs to maintain authentication for my app with Azure ad or does it pass my credentials everytime

Comment: Actualy from the readings you posted it looks like client credential flow will grant a app-only token. I guess I can store that in cache similar to how I did delegated permissions?

Comment: `Since we may shift to Okta and away from AAD for authenticating users` then yes you can try to stay away from delegated permissions. And when we use client credential flow, we don't need to change any code in program.cs unless you want to do a DI, I mean you can certainly make my code to be a service and inject it. For me, when I want to call MS Graph API  with client credential flow, I always generate a new graph client just like what I wrote. In production environment, we can certainly inject it so that we don't need to new this graphClient.

Comment: Ahhh thank you for that. Makes sense. I am just surprised there is no tokens/refresh tokens for the app passed around for more secure access but maybe thats the point of the credential flow since its server to server it doesnt matter.

Comment: yes, we can only get access token from client credential flow, and refresh token is only available for auth code flow.  `var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;
`